# Can someone help me find the error in my python program?

Tags: python, pygame

Hi here is my error and my python program
I have been stuck on this for a week and desperately need some help
If anyone knows what the error is and how to solve it, please comment down below!
I will be grateful for any help!
This is copied from a python tutorial and it is not working

```
import pygame
import sys
import math
pygame.init()


def cropSurface(newWidth,newHeight,cropWidth,cropHeight,
                image):
    newSurf=pygame.Surface((newWidth,newHeight),
                          pygame.SRCALPHA,32)
    newSurf.blit(image,(0,0),(cropWidth,cropHeight,
                              newWidth,newHeight))
    return newSurf

def movePlayer(direction,radius,absRot):
    yChange=5
    deltaTheta=int(90/(radius/yChange))
    if direction=="Left":
        deltaTheta*=-1

    finalRot=(absRot+deltaTheta)*math.pi/180

    Hypotenuse=(radius*math.sin(finalRot)/
                (math.sin((math.pi-finalRot)/2)))

    newX=Hypotenuse*math.cos(math.pi/2-(math.pi-finalRot)/2)
    newY=Hypotenuse*math.sin(math.pi/2-(math.pi-finalRot)/2)

    return newX,newY,absRot+deltaTheta
def updateFrameImages(showFoot=False):
    global screen,grassImage,goalLeft,goalMiddle,goalRight
    global ball,player,goalStart,ballX,ballY
    global playerX,playerY
    screen.blit(grassImage,(0,0))
    screen.blit(goalLeft,(goalStart,0))
    screen.blit(goalMiddle,(goalStart+
                        goalLeft.get_rect().width,
                        0))
    screen.blit(goalRight,(goalStart+
                       goalLeft.get_rect().width+
                       goalMiddle.get_rect().width,
                       0))
    if showFoot:
        global foot,footX,footY
        screen.blit(foot,(footX-foot.get_rect().width/2,
                          footY-foot.get_rect().height/2))
        
        screen.blit(ball,(ballX-ball.get_rect().width/2,
                      ballY-ball.get_rect().height/2))
            
        screen.blit(player,(playerX-player.get_rect().width/2,
                        playerY-player.get_rect().height/2))
width=900
height=700
screenDim=(width,height)

screen=pygame.display.set_mode(screenDim)

pygame.display.set_caption("my second game")

grassImage=pygame.image.load("23.2_-_grass.png").convert()
grassImage=pygame.transform.scale(grassImage,(width,height))
screen.blit(grassImage,(0,0))


rescale=3
player=pygame.image.load("24.4_-_characterBody.png").convert_alpha()
playerWidth=player.get_rect().width
playerHeight=player.get_rect().height
player=pygame.transform.scale(player,(playerWidth*rescale,playerHeight*rescale))
player=pygame.transform.rotate(player,90)
playerStart=player
currentRotation=0
playerStart=player
currentRotation=0
foot=pygame.image.load("24.3_-_characterFoot.png").convert_alpha()
footWidth=foot.get_rect().width
footHeight=foot.get_rect().height
foot=pygame.transform.scale(foot,(footWidth*rescale,footHeight*rescale))
foot=pygame.transform.rotate(foot,90)
footStart=foot

rescaleBall=2
ball=pygame.image.load("24.2_-_ball.png").convert_alpha()
ballWidth=ball.get_rect().width
ballHeight=ball.get_rect().height
ball=pygame.transform.scale(ball,(ballWidth*rescaleBall,ballHeight*rescaleBall))



goalLeft=pygame.image.load("25.2_-_goalLeft.png").convert_alpha()
goalLeft=pygame.transform.scale(goalLeft,(250,270))
goalLeftWidth=goalLeft.get_rect().width
goalLeftHeight=goalLeft.get_rect().height
adjust=12
goalLeft=cropSurface(goalLeftWidth/2+adjust,
                     goalLeftHeight/2+adjust,
                     goalLeftWidth/2-adjust,
                     goalLeftHeight/2-adjust,
                goalLeft)


goalMiddle=pygame.image.load("26.2_-_goalMiddle.png").convert()
goalMiddle=pygame.transform.scale(goalMiddle,(250,270))
goalMiddleWidth=goalMiddle.get_rect().width
goalMiddleHeight=goalMiddle.get_rect().height
goalMiddle=cropSurface(goalMiddleWidth,
                       goalMiddleHeight/2+adjust,
                       0,
                       goalMiddleHeight/2-adjust,
                       goalMiddle)


goalRight=pygame.image.load("26.3_-_goalRight.png").convert_alpha()
goalRight=pygame.transform.scale(goalRight,(250,270))
goalRightWidth=goalRight.get_rect().width
goalRightHeight=goalRight.get_rect().height

goalRight=cropSurface(goalRightWidth/2+adjust,goalRightHeight/2+adjust,0,goalRightHeight/2-adjust,goalRight)


goalStart=(width-goalLeft.get_rect().width-
           goalMiddle.get_rect().width-
           goalRight.get_rect().width)/2

screen.blit(goalLeft,(goalStart,0))
screen.blit(goalMiddle,(goalStart+goalLeft.get_rect().width,0))
screen.blit(goalRight,(goalStart+goalLeft.get_rect().width+goalMiddle.get_rect().width,0))


playerX=width/2
playerY=530

playerXOriginal=playerX
playerYOriginal=playerY
#screen.blit(foot,(0,0))
screen.blit(player,(playerX-player.get_rect().width/2,
                    playerY-player.get_rect().height/2))
ballX=width/2
ballY=450

radius=playerY-ballY
screen.blit(ball,(ballX-ball.get_rect().width/2,
                  ballY-ball.get_rect().height/2))

frame=pygame.time.Clock()
finished = False
while finished ==False:
    #a;slkdjf;alskdjf;aslkdjf;a;dlkfj
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #a;fjallkdjfaa;lakjdf;ala;sdkfja;
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            finished=True
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pressedKeys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    print(pygame.K_LEFT)
    
    if pressedKeys[pygame.K_LEFT]==1:
        if currentRotation>-90:
            changeX,changeY,currentRotation=movePlayer("Left",radius,currentRotation)
            player=pygame.transform.rotate(playerStart,currentRotation)
            playerX=playerXOriginal+changeX
            playerY=playerYOriginal-changeY
        
    elif pressedKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT]==1:
        if currentRotation<90:
            changeX,changeY,currentRotation=movePlayer("Right",radius,currentRotation)
            player=pygame.transform.rotate(playerStart,currentRotation)
            playerX=playerXOriginal+changeX
            playerY=playerYOriginal-changeY
        
    elif pressedKeys[pygame.K_SPACE]==1:
        xMove=(playerX-ballX)/10
        yMove=(playerY-ballY)/10
        normMove=1/math.sqrt(xMove**2+yMove**2)
        distanceToShoulder=20
        shoulderAngle=currentRotation*math.pi/180
        for i in range(3):
            playerX-=xMove
            playerY-=yMove
            updateFrameImages()
            pygame.display.flip()
            frame.tick(30)
        footX=(playerX+distanceToShoulder*math.cos(shoulderAngle)-25*xMove*normMove)
        footY=(playerY-distanceToShoulder*math.sin(shoulderAngle)-25*yMove*normMove)
        foot=pygame.transform.rotate(footStart,currentrotation)
        updateFrameImages()
    #wwwwwwwwww
    updateFrameImages(True)
    pygame.display.flip()
            
    screen.blit(player,(playerX-player.get_rect().width/2,
                        playerY-player.get_rect().height/2))
    pygame.display.flip()
    frame.tick(30)
```

and here is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Divija\Downloads\Udemy Master Python Interactively With PyGame Ultimate Bootcamp_git.ir\5_-_Files_And_Images\py.py", line 191, in <module>
    updateFrameImages(True)
  File "C:\Users\Divija\Downloads\Udemy Master Python Interactively With PyGame Ultimate Bootcamp_git.ir\5_-_Files_And_Images\py.py", line 45, in updateFrameImages
    screen.blit(foot,(footX-foot.get_rect().width/2,
NameError: name 'footX' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the given code and error message, the variable "footX" has been referred as global variable but it has not been defined anywhere globally in your code.

This piece of code might make it clear why you are getting this error

```
footX = "some value" # you get error if this line is commented out


def my_func():
    global footX
    print("here footX is accessed as a global variable with value {}".format(footX))


my_func()
```

Also I have noticed that the `footX` variable in your code is getting declared in a if else block and the function using this variable is called later.

So it might be the case that the particular `elif` block ( which create `footX` variable ) is not executed and this gives error in `UpdateFrameImages` function.

#### Possible Solution:

The `UpdateFrameImages` function uses footX only when `showFoot=True`. So initially, `showFoot` argument can be set to False when`footX` is not defined.

When footX is defined i.e in the elif block, then set `showFoot = True` when calling `UpdateFrameImages`.

NOTE : *Also I have changed `currentrotation` to `currentRotation` since `currentrotation` wasn't defined anywhere.*

I have made these changes in the while loop as follows, just replace it with your while loop:

```
while finished ==False:
    #a;slkdjf;alskdjf;aslkdjf;a;dlkfj
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #a;fjallkdjfaa;lakjdf;ala;sdkfja;
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            finished=True
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pressedKeys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    print(pygame.K_LEFT)
    
    if pressedKeys[pygame.K_LEFT]==1:
        if currentRotation>-90:
            changeX,changeY,currentRotation=movePlayer("Left",radius,currentRotation)
            player=pygame.transform.rotate(playerStart,currentRotation)
            playerX=playerXOriginal+changeX
            playerY=playerYOriginal-changeY
        
    elif pressedKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT]==1:
        if currentRotation<90:
            changeX,changeY,currentRotation=movePlayer("Right",radius,currentRotation)
            player=pygame.transform.rotate(playerStart,currentRotation)
            playerX=playerXOriginal+changeX
            playerY=playerYOriginal-changeY
        
    elif pressedKeys[pygame.K_SPACE]==1:
        xMove=(playerX-ballX)/10
        yMove=(playerY-ballY)/10
        normMove=1/math.sqrt(xMove**2+yMove**2)
        distanceToShoulder=20
        shoulderAngle=currentRotation*math.pi/180
        for i in range(3):
            playerX-=xMove
            playerY-=yMove
            updateFrameImages()
            pygame.display.flip()
            frame.tick(30)
        footX=(playerX+distanceToShoulder*math.cos(shoulderAngle)-25*xMove*normMove)
        footY=(playerY-distanceToShoulder*math.sin(shoulderAngle)-25*yMove*normMove)
        foot=pygame.transform.rotate(footStart,currentRotation) #changed 'currentotation' to 'currentRotation'
        updateFrameImages(True) # true beacuse now footX is defined
    #wwwwwwwwww
    updateFrameImages(False) #false since footX not defined initially
    pygame.display.flip()
            
    screen.blit(player,(playerX-player.get_rect().width/2,
                        playerY-player.get_rect().height/2))
    pygame.display.flip()
    frame.tick(30)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I do not understand. Please could you tell me how to I fix the error and is there something I should rearrange to make it work?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond immediately as I was in school.

Comment: no prob, I have edited my answer, see if it works as you want?